# TeXShop always open the pdf file

Tags: editors, texshop, macos

I run TeXShop on a MacBook Air. There are some strange problems. When I open a `.tex` file, TeXShop always typesetting automatically and show me the result `.pdf` file. The code file doesn't occur. But I just want to edit the source file with extension .tex. Unless I open the `.tex` file in the menu "open to edit" of TeXShop, I cant see the file I want to edit. Another problem is that I cant set the default size of font displaying in the source window. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no "open to edit" in my TeXShop. Would you like to update your TeXShop? It is currently 3.41.2.

Comment: @symbol My texShop is a Chinese version. So maybe the english name is not “open to edit” exactly. The version is 3.41.

Comment: But... my TeXShop has only english menu. Did you download TeXShop from website other than [tug.org/mactex](https://tug.org/mactex/)?

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you. I have resolve the problem by install another pkg.

Comment: @MiGang I have the same problem, what package did you install to resolve this?

Comment: @iamaziz It can be done in the preference. Preference - source code - setting as external editor, remove the checkmark.

Comment: @MiGang great thanks a lot!
In my case, it was: preference > source > Configure for External Editor (uncheck).